# perl regex to accept exactly 1 not alphanumeric (\W) character

Tags: regex, perl

the title explain the question itself.

more specifically i need to write a regex in order to accept a "question", something like: `"how are you today?"`. So the last character must be a `"?"`.
I tried something like this:

```
m/[^a-zA-Z0-9\W{1}]/
```

but it accept any input with `1` or more `\W` character

Comment: `So the last character must be a "?"` And you need a regex just to validate this?

Comment: The above regex by @vks will not match that *"how are you today?"* sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex you gave in your question does not do what you think it does.

> ```
> m/[^a-zA-Z0-9\W{1}]/
> ```

This will match any character that is **not** `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, any non word character (`\W`), `{`, or `}`. The `^` inside the square brackets negate the content of the char group. It's not the beginning of the line if it's in there!

If you need to validate any input that has a questionmark at at the end, all you need it the questionmark and the end-of-line metacharacer.

```
/\?$/
```

The `?` is a metacharacter itself, so you need to escape it with a backslash (`\`).

If you want to match a whole sentence with the questionmark at the end, think of what kinds of characters could be in the sentence. It will not only be `\w` probably.

---

Play around with your input and your regex on http://regex101.com/, that will make it easier because it explains what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

This may works:

```
if( $question =~ m!([\w\s]+)\?$! ) {
   print "question text: $1\n";
}
```

The regexpr looks for \w and \s (spaces, tabs, ...) you often have in a text before the question mark at the last position

Answer (score 0):

> accept a "question", something like:"how are you today?"

How about:

```
$string =~ /^(?:[a-z0-9]+\s*)+\?$/i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I hope to you expect match any character in preceding the `?`, this is favor for you

```
'm/[.+\?$]/ '
```

`.`is helps to match the any character of the string
`\`Ignore the function of the `? (match 0 or 1 time in preceding character)` then `$` matches the last character.